# How to increase the maxlenght in web.Config and App.Config to upload the image?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-config, app-config

In my program I am trying to save image to database. I am getting an exception

> protocol exception was unhandled" The remote server returned an unexpected response (400) Bad Request

I looked up on google and I found to change maximum message length in `app.config`. I tried that but even that did not work. Here is my `app.config`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
     <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
         <basicHttpBinding>
           <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
              openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
              allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"  
              hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              maxBufferSize="524288" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288"
              messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
           useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
               maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
         <security mode="None">
         <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
         <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
       </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
       <endpoint address="http://localhost:55750/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="PeerService.IService1"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </client>
     </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

Can you please tell me how to fix it?I am really stuck in this problem....

Comment: Is this a REST service?  You may be running up against the default size limit for IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upping all your values:

```
<!-- Used by basic WCF Services -->
<binding maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="20000000" maxArrayLength="20000000" maxBytesPerRead="20000000" maxNameTableCharCount="20000000"/>
</binding>
```